# How can I install youtube's lens for unity?

Tags: 11.04, lenses

the question says it all. I would love to install the youtube lens but I see no trace of it online.

The only clue I had was that it was a contributor of OMG Ubuntu in an article from OMG Ubuntu. It had no link.

Comment: The OMG Ubuntu article: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/five-neat-unity-lenses-in-development/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can. The post says "The following YouTube Lens for Unity, currently knee-high in development by a certain regular OMG! Ubuntu! contributor". Even if you get the source from their ppa and build it yourself, it might be buggy since it's still in development.

I would recommend Minitube, it's the primary Youtube app on my Natty system.